# Lendo arquivo longo por partes

Tags: arquivo

Eu tenho o seguinte código onde leio e imprimo partes de um arquivo longo de quase
5 milhões de linhas.

O meu problema, é que não consigo imprimir mais do que 64443 linhas deste arquivo, o que não representa quase nada comparado ao tamanho total do mesmo.

Ficaria satisfeito se eu conseguisse imprimir estas 64443 linhas de uma forma aleatória, ou sequencialmente continuando a partir de onde para a impressão.

Alguém poderia dar uma dica?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    char *matriz;
    matriz = ( char * ) malloc ( 1000000 );//1 milhão de bytes ou 1MB
    int i;
    FILE *arq = fopen("Meuarquivo.txt", "r" );//113MB
    if ( arq == NULL ){
        textcolor(YELLOW);gotoxy(26,12);
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo ");
        getche();
        return (0);
    }
    textcolor(WHITE);
    for ( i = 0; i < 64443; i++ ) {//Só lê e imprime até esta linha 64443.
        fgets ( matriz, 255, arq );
        printf("%d %s ", i, matriz );
    }
    //Tentei realocar mais memória más não adianta, a contagem
    //das linhas prossegue, más sai vazio, não imprime mais nada do arquivo
    //tentei resetar a matriz de várias forma, para preencher com dados
    //a partir da linha 64443 más também não resolveu.
    matriz = ( char * ) realloc ( matriz, 2000000  );//2 milhões de bytes ou 2MB
    textcolor(WHITE);
    for ( i = 64443; i < 128000; i++ ) {
        fgets ( matriz, 255, arq );
        printf("%d %s ", i, matriz );
    }
    fclose(arq);
    getche();
}
```

Comment: Parecido más não igual

Comment: Alguem poderia editar o código, tá uma bagunça.rss...

Comment: Nesse caso de semelhança, resolvendo um, resolve-se o outro com um pouco de esforço.

Comment: Muito obrigado tente neste por favor!!

Comment: A resposta no outro post não me serviu de nada, não funciona.

Comment: Mesmo assim, parece ser a mesma pergunta, então é melhor esperar outra resposta por lá.